# Closing all jquery dialog windows in JavaScript

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

How does one close all jquery ui dialog windows in javascript?

Situation:

The page has multiple things that can be opened using the dialog boxes.  I need a way to close all previous windows before opening a new one.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

They all have the `.ui-dialog-content` class, so select by that and close them, like this:

```
$(".ui-dialog-content").dialog("close");
```

Comment: Thank you.  I don't know how I've missed that.

Comment: Any way to do it if there are different classes?

Comment: @bobek - absolutely, just separate them in your selector by a comma, for example `$(".class1, .class2")`

Comment: This only outputs "jQuery()" for me in the firebug console.

Comment: Careful! For dialogs in the HTML that have not yet been initialized, this can result in an error. A working solution is here: stackoverflow.com/a/9060927/368896

Answer (score 2):

Be careful with the above. If you define a close method for your dialog, it will get fired even if the dialog is not open. This was a huge issue in an Angular project where we were manually calling $apply() in our dialog close method. Another event was trying to close all dialogs on the screen and our close method was called even though wasn't open resulting in a digest issue.